# avoid mobile numbers less than ten digits? PHP

Tags: php

How to avoid mobile numbers less than ten digits? My code is given below. Above ten digits are not allowed. But less than ten digits are taken. Please how to sort the numbers if they are only 10 digit ?

```
foreach ($phone_numbers as $key => $phone_number) {
            $phone_number = ltrim($phone_number, "0");
            $phone_number = substr($phone_number, -10);
            $phone_number = str_replace("+", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace(" ", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("'", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("`", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("\"", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("-", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("/", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("_", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("*", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("#", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace(",", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace(".", "", $phone_number);
            $phone_number = str_replace("=", "", $phone_number);
            $country_code = '91';
            $phone_number = trim($country_code.$phone_number);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of guessing what characters the user is going to enter why not use regex?

```
$phone_nuber_digits = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $phone_number);
$number_digits = strlen($phone_nuber_digits);
```

Now you can check how long is your phone number to make sure that is 10 digits

Comment: regex Tried it many times. But did not succeed.